# Find, Group and Merge Overlapping Date Time ranges to determine "full range"

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Apologies for some of the terminology. This is a difficult problem to explain.

I am trying to determine the actual time in a dataset with records containing duplicate and overlapping date time ranges.

Below is a test dataset of a duplicated and overlapping records.

```
            var records = new List<Record>
            {
                new Record { Name = "Group1 - A", Start = new DateTime(2024, 1, 1, 9, 0, 0), End = new DateTime(2024, 1, 1, 10, 0, 0) },
                new Record { Name = "Group1 - B", Start = new DateTime(2024, 1, 1, 9, 30, 0), End = new DateTime(2024, 1, 1, 11, 0, 0) },
                new Record { Name = "Group1 - C", Start = new DateTime(2024, 1, 1, 10, 30, 0), End = new DateTime(2024, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0) },
                new Record { Name = "Group2 - D", Start = new DateTime(2024, 1, 1, 13, 0, 0), End = new DateTime(2024, 1, 1, 15, 0, 0) },
                new Record { Name = "Group3 - E", Start = new DateTime(2024, 1, 2, 22, 0, 0), End = new DateTime(2024, 1, 2, 23, 0, 0) },
                new Record { Name = "Group3 - F", Start = new DateTime(2024, 1, 2, 22, 30, 0), End = new DateTime(2024, 1, 3, 5, 0, 0) }
            };
```

I am expecting the above records to be merged into the below three results. Where the Start is the min Start date time of the grouped records and the End is the max End date time of the group records.

```
Group 1 – Start: 1/1/2024 9am, End: 1/1/2024 12pm
Group 2 - Start: 1/1/2024 1pm, End: 1/1/2024 3pm
Group 3 - Start: 2/1/2024 10pm, End: 3/1/2024 5am
```

I have been trying various LINQ queries with a group by but I am not getting anywhere close.

Is it possible to solve this using LINQ?

Before anyone asks the solution is preferably a LINQ query as this is what is passed into a rules engine.

Comment: The code sample seems to have all `DateTime`s with year 2024 while the grouping results have the year 2023.

Comment: Group 3 is completey incorrect, too. Should be 2014-01-**03**, 5AM. As is, it **End**s before it **Start**s...

Comment: How do you define a "group" here? Is it enough that two records overlap, or do you want to use parts of the name?

Answer (score 0):

yes there is a way to do this using LINQ. You can make use of the group by and  group the records by a common key and then calculate the minimum start time and maximum end time for each group.

Here is the code:

```
var groupedRecords = records
    .GroupBy(r => r.Name.Split('-')[0].Trim()) // Group by the common part of the Name
    .Select(group => new
    {
        GroupName = group.Key,
        Start = group.Min(r => r.Start),
        End = group.Max(r => r.End)
    })
    .ToList();

    foreach (var group in groupedRecords)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{group.GroupName} - Start: {group.Start:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt}, End: {group.End:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt}");
    }
```

Output:

```
Group1 - Start: 01/01/2024 09:00 AM, End: 01/01/2024 12:00 PM
Group2 - Start: 01/01/2024 01:00 PM, End: 01/01/2024 03:00 PM
Group3 - Start: 02/01/2024 10:00 PM, End: 03/01/2024 05:00 AM
```